# Convert vector of shared_ptr into the vector of raw pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I was wondering if there are ways to convert the vector of shared pointers into the vector of raw pointers other than doing it through the loop:

```
\\vecShared - initial vector of shared pointers
std::vector< double* > vecRaw;

for(unsigned int i=0; i<vecShared .size(); ++i)
    vecRaw.push_back(vecShared[i].get());
```

If there are other ways, is there an advantage of using those?

Comment: Why do you need to do it?

Comment: You could use std::transform, but why bother, a loop is simple and obvious to everyone.

Comment: What ownership do you expect after the loop? If elements from `vecShared` are deleted, then `vecRaw` will include dangling pointers. Is this okay for your use case?

Comment: @UnholySheep I have to use this vector of shared pointers within the class that I am working on. But some other classes are using vectors of raw pointers.

Comment: Be careful if you do. If you lose track of the `std::shared_ptr` instances (e.g. the `std::vector` holding them goes out of scope) your raw pointers might point to inaccessible memory. Why wouldn't you keep using the `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: Loop is fine, and you can make it shorter: `for (const auto& shared : vecShared) vecRaw.push_back(shared.get());`

Comment: You can also add vecRaw.reserve(vecShared.size()) as a small optimization before the loop.

Comment: @Link64 I see, thx. If I keep it, I will need to overload methods of other classes where this vector is passed.

Comment: I think it's fine to have a collection of smart pointers while passing another container with raw pointers around - smart pointers express ownership, raw pointers don't. If you have an API that has nothing to do with any ownership semantics, it may very well operate on raw pointers. Or `std::reference_wrapper`, this might be a tweak worthwile to eliminate the `nullptr` state.

Answer (score 1):

Of course

```
vecRaw.reserve(vecShared.size());
std::transform(vecShared.cbegin(), vecShared.cend(), std::back_inserter(vecRaw),
    [](auto& ptr) { return ptr.get(); });
```

Comment: Which is basically a loop